How to Properly Discretize Semiconductor Continuity Equations
I am looking to perform numerical modeling of a MOSFET device and am wanting to better understand how to discretize the semiconductor continuity equations. The semiconductor equations consist of the following five equations:
Poisson's equation:
$$
\nabla^2\psi = \frac{q}{\varepsilon}[p-n +N_d-N_a]
$$
Electron & hole drift diffusion equations:
$$
J_n = q μ_n nE + q D_n \frac{dn}{dx}\\
J_p = q μ_p pE + q D_p \frac{dp}{dx} 
$$
Electron & hole continuity equations (ignoring generation and recombination):
$$
-q\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = \nabla\cdot J_n\\
-q\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = \nabla\cdot J_p
$$
Poisson's equation can easily be discretized in the following manner (shown in one dimension for simplicity):
$$
\psi_{i} = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\psi_{i-1} + \psi_{i+1} - \frac{q_i}{\varepsilon} \bigg]
$$
which can be iterated over using appropriate boundary conditions to find a solution for the potential. My confusion however is related to the discretization of the drift-diffusion coupled with the continuity requirements. In the many, many sources I have read, only one lists a similar equation for the carrier concentration in terms of nearby elements. Is there a reason the drift diffusion equations are not typically discretized in a similar manner as the Poisson equation? Secondly, the carrier concentrations can be written in terms of the quasi-fermi level, $\phi$, and $\psi$ in the following way:
$$
n=n_i\exp(\frac{q(\psi-\phi_n}{kT})
$$
This can be inverted to get the quasi-fermi level in terms of the carrier concentration:
$$
\phi_n = \psi - kT\ln(n/n_i)
$$
My second question then is can I instead treat the quasi-fermi levels as the quantity to be iterated over, and use them to then solve for the carrier concentration, which I can plug into the Poisson equation? If so, what would the equivalent iterative procedure be? And what would be the appropriate boundary conditions? To put it succinctly, I feel very comfortable solving the Poisson equation and lost as to where to go next to perform full MOSFET modeling.

Can you specify what quantity you want to solve for? From what I see, you can numerically solve for $\psi$ using the first equation by first having the solution for $n$ and $p$ which you can obtain by solving the other four. Is that correct?

The quantity I would like to solve for is the drain current in terms of the gate voltage and source voltage. First Poisson’s equation is iteratively solved for until a solution is converged upon. Then the carrier concentrations are recalculated. This is done repeatedly until a final solution is derived. Or at least that is my current understanding, but I have not been successful yet so I could be mistaken.
